# Jenkins - To see any failure icon if test fails , even if the build passes

Tags: jenkins

Goal : 
I needed the maven build cycle to be completed/successful so a report would be generated.
But how can I show in Jenkins that there a test failure without canceling the build?

-Steps:

1. mvn clean verify
2. test runs
3. see's test method passes or fail
4. build is successful, a report is generated.

-Wants :

1. In Jenkins - show a red icon if there is a failure in the test (TestNg) despite the build is successful.

-Why? :

1. I don't want to view the report every day just to see if there's a failure.
2. Quick glance at the Jenkins Dashboard to see if there was a failure.

Here's my console output for context.

```
10:51:16 
10:51:16 ===============================================
10:51:16     TEST FRAMEWORK DEMO 1 PASS 1 FAIL
10:51:16     Tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
10:51:16 ===============================================
10:51:16 
10:51:16 [ERROR] Tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 5.405 s <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
10:51:16 [ERROR] com.demo.runnertypes.DemoTest.runScenario  Time elapsed: 1.473 s  <<< FAILURE!
10:51:16 org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: 
10:51:16 invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //input[@id='password']invalidXpath because of the following error:
10:51:16 SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//input[@id='password']invalidXpath' is not a valid XPath expression.
10:51:16   (Session info: headless chrome=78.0.3904.97)
10:51:16 For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html
10:51:16 Build info: version: '3.6.0', revision: '6fbf3ec767', time: '2017-09-27T15:28:36.4Z'
10:51:16 System info: host: 'fmdat01ap01.unix.ctcwest.ctc', ip: '192.168.241.251', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-1062.4.1.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_212'
10:51:16 Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
10:51:16 Capabilities [{networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=77.0.3865.40 (f484704e052e0b556f8030b65b953dce96503217-refs/branch-heads/3865@{#442}), userDataDir=/tmp/.com.google.Chrome.kiacKj}, timeouts={implicit=0, pageLoad=300000, script=30000}, pageLoadStrategy=normal, unhandledPromptBehavior=dismiss and notify, strictFileInteractability=false, platform=LINUX, proxy=Proxy(), goog:chromeOptions={debuggerAddress=localhost:33385}, acceptInsecureCerts=false, browserVersion=78.0.3904.97, browserName=chrome, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=LINUX, setWindowRect=true}]
10:51:16 Session ID: d6c2fbc4cbbd341cf6ef05609cb1e7a0
10:51:16 *** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//input[@id='password']invalidXpath}
10:51:16 
10:51:16 [INFO] 
10:51:16 [INFO] Results:
10:51:16 [INFO] 
10:51:16 [ERROR] Failures: 
10:51:16 [ERROR] com.demo.runnertypes.DemoTest.runScenario
10:51:16 [INFO]   Run 1: PASS
10:51:16 [ERROR]   Run 2: DemoTest.runScenario » InvalidSelector invalid selector: Unable to locate an e...
10:51:16 [INFO] 
10:51:16 [INFO] 
10:51:16 [ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
10:51:16 [INFO] 
10:51:16 [ERROR] There are test failures.
10:51:16 
10:51:16 Please refer to /home/fmdigi/data/jenkins/workspace/CucumberTest/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
10:51:16 Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
10:51:16 [INFO] 
10:51:16 [INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ testframework ---
10:51:17 [INFO] Building jar: /home/fmdigi/data/jenkins/workspace/CucumberTest/target/testframework-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
10:51:17 [INFO] 
10:51:17 [INFO] --- cluecumber-report-plugin:2.3.1:reporting (report) @ testframework ---
10:51:17 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
10:51:17 [INFO]  Cluecumber Report Maven Plugin, version 2.3.1
10:51:17 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
10:51:17 [INFO] - source JSON report directory     : /home/fmdigi/data/jenkins/workspace/CucumberTest/target/cucumber-report
10:51:17 [INFO] - generated HTML report directory  : test-report/generated-cluecumber-report
10:51:17 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
10:51:17 [INFO] - fail pending/undefined scenarios : false
10:51:17 [INFO] - expand before/after hooks        : true
10:51:17 [INFO] - expand step hooks                : false
10:51:17 [INFO] - expand doc strings               : false
10:51:17 [INFO] - page title                       : Cluecumber Report
10:51:17 [INFO] - colors (passed, failed, skipped) : #28a745, #dc3545, #ffc107
10:51:17 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
10:51:17 [INFO] => Cluecumber Report: test-report/generated-cluecumber-report/index.html
10:51:17 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
10:51:17 [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
10:51:17 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
10:51:17 [INFO] Total time: 10.711 s
10:51:17 [INFO] Finished at: 2019-11-19T10:51:47-07:00
10:51:18 [INFO] Final Memory: 28M/571M
10:51:18 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
10:51:18 [htmlpublisher] Archiving HTML reports...
10:51:18 [htmlpublisher] Archiving at BUILD level /home/fmdigi/data/jenkins/workspace/CucumberTest/test-output/HtmlReport to /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/CucumberTest/builds/15/htmlreports/ExtentHtml_Report
10:51:18 [htmlpublisher] Archiving at BUILD level /home/fmdigi/data/jenkins/workspace/CucumberTest/test-report/generated-cluecumber-report to /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/CucumberTest/builds/15/htmlreports/Test_Report
10:51:18 Collecting metadata...
10:51:18 Metadata collection done.
10:51:18 Finished: SUCCESS
```

POM.xml build phase

```
   <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                        <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <extent.reporter.html.start>true</extent.reporter.html.start>
                        <extent.reporter.html.out>test-output/HtmlReport/ExtentHtml.html</extent.reporter.html.out>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.trivago.rta</groupId>
                <artifactId>cluecumber-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${cluecumber-report.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>reporting</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <sourceJsonReportDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-report</sourceJsonReportDirectory>
                    <generatedHtmlReportDirectory>test-report/generated-cluecumber-report</generatedHtmlReportDirectory>
                    <expandBeforeAfterHooks>true</expandBeforeAfterHooks>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.googlecode.maven-download-plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>download-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-download-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install-chrome-driver-linux64</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wget</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <url>
                                https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/${chromedriver-dep.version}/chromedriver_linux64.zip
                            </url>
                            <unpack>true</unpack>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/drivers/linux/64bit/</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install-chrome-driver-windows</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wget</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <url>
                                https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/${chromedriver-dep.version}/chromedriver_win32.zip
                            </url>
                            <unpack>true</unpack>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/drivers/windows/</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install-chrome-driver-osx</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wget</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <url>
                                https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/${chromedriver-dep.version}/chromedriver_mac64.zip
                            </url>
                            <unpack>true</unpack>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/drivers/osx/</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: Show the **significant** portions of your pom: what plugin are you using to run your tests, what plugin are you using to generate your report, plus their configurations.

Comment: @SiKing TestNg basically. I think I can use the TestNg Plugin found in Jenkins.

Comment: @SiKing also added the build phase of the POM

Comment: @SiKing Unfortunately the proposed solution didnt work for me. Commented any surefire plugin and just used the failsafe - when the build fails, the report isnt generated.

Answer (score 1):

I have all my Selenium tests in a separate project, away from other code. If this is not your case, the following might break your build!

Turn off the Surefire plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${surefire.plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <skipTests>true</skipTests>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And substitute the [Failsafe plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/usage.html):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${surefire.plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>integration-test</goal>
          <goal>verify</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Note that the versions are **intentionally the same**!

From [Failsafe site](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/):

> The Failsafe Plugin is designed to run integration tests while the Surefire Plugin is designed to run unit tests. The name (failsafe) was chosen both because it is a synonym of surefire and because it implies that when it fails, it does so in a safe way.

What this means is that when integration-tests fail, the build will continue, and will run your report which you have correctly defined in `<phase>post-integration-test</phase>`.

In order for Failsafe to pickup your tests, you can either rename everything from `*Test` to `*IT`, or configure the Failsafe plugin to pick your tests, explained [here](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html). Note that almost all configurations for Failsafe are the same as for Surefire. You might also want to read the [TestNG configuration section](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/testng.html).

You will still run everything just as you did, with: `mvn clean verify`.

One *secret* thing that Jenkins does is it overrides how integration-test failures are handled, using the [testFailureIgnore flag](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/verify-mojo.html#testFailureIgnore). Jenkins overrides the default behaviour and will not flag the build as failed (the red icon). So for Jenkins you must set it back. This can easily be done in your pom with configuration `<testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>`, or in Jenkins with setting `MAVEN_OPTS` to `-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=false`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the JUnit Plugin - via `Publish JUnit test result report` - made the build icon yellow/red depending on the config I wanted.